# 3次元行列の次元の表し方において、1行、1列、あと何？

Tags: 数学, 行列

2次元行列の表し方として、*n*行*m*列、と言いますが、3次元行列においては日本語としてどのように表現するべきですか？

英語圏でも表現が定まっていないようで、次の例が挙げられていました。

```
 1. row・column・aisle  → 行・列・通路
 2. row・column・page   → 行・列・頁
 3. row・column・slice  → 行・列・切片
 4. row・column・depth  → 行・列・奥行
 5. row・column・strata → 行・列・層
```

日本語にしたときに自然なのは、2もしくは5だと考えています。
何か上記以外の表現方法や、特定の業界ではこれが使われている等があればお教えください。

Comment: 参考情報ですが、MATLABのドキュメントでは、"ページ"または"シート"と呼んでいるようです。 https://jp.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html

Comment: 有益な情報をありがとうございます。
シートは日本語訳にした際、1枚と数えることができるので、リズム感もいいですね！

Comment: 「皆様の意見を聞かせてください」だと、このサイトにふさわしくないアンケートの質問になる印象です。[どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)。意見を求めるのではなく、事実を確認するような質問だったらよいと思います。「最も使われている表現は何ですか？」「そのようは表現の揺れをまとめたサイトはありますか？」「特定の分野や業界において決まった呼び方がありますか？」的な感じでしょうか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。参考url確認しました。ご指摘通り良い質問ではないですね。ご教授いただいた内容を参考に修正しました。ありがとうございます。